# MeasureText SkiaSharp vs WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, skiasharp

I need to measure text height and width using SkiaSharp. This is my SkiaSharp code:

```
        SKPaint p = new SKPaint
        {
            Typeface = font.Typeface,
            TextSize = font.Size
        }
        var textBounds = new SKRect(boxSize.Width, boxSize.Height, 0, 0);
        p.MeasureText(text, ref textBounds);
```

and my old code:

```
System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, font, boxSize);
```

SkiaSharp code returns width:5, height:6
MeasureText code return width:15, height:17
for same font, text and boxSize

AFAIK MeasureText uses DPI machine DPI and SkiaSharp defaults to 72 but I have no idea what to do with this information.

1. How can I write my SkiaSharp code to return same values as MeasureText?
2. How can I check what DPI value TextRenderer.MeasureText used?

Comment: Points, not pixels.  Pixels = points * dpi / 72.  Looks like you have your monitor set to 200%, so dpi is 192 pixels per inch.  So width = 5 * 192 / 72 = 14 pixels, height = 6 * 192 / 72 = 16 pixels.  Good example of the loss of accuracy btw, tells you why winforms designers preferred pixels.

Comment: `TextRenderer.MeasureText()` uses the Screen DC if no `IDeviceContext`  has been specified, as in your case. As `IDeviceContext`, you usually pass the contextual Graphics object

Comment: By monitor set to 200% do you mean windows scaling? I have it set 100% (15x17 is for 100%) - but TextRenderer reacts when I increase it for example to 125% then values also are 1,25 higher, but I don't know where that 192 comes from. I checked it on 2 monitors and its the same for 1080p and 1440p